# Calculate small rotations from displacements

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-kinematics

I am performing a modal test on a cantilevered beam-like structure, free at one end and fixed at the other end but with flexible constraints, similar to rotational springs in all 3 directions. The structure is excited and the mode shapes estimated by measuring the response of a triaxial accelerometer at the free end. The results are displacements in three directions.
I have also a FE model of the same structure, where DOFs are both small displacements and small rotations of the free end. Is it possible to compute the infinitesimal small rotations of the experimental mode shapes from the displacements?